# new list added - to show in Content query web part (CQWP)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part

How Content Query Web Part (CQWP) will be able to show new list added to its output? By default it cann't show new list but how to customize this?

Answer (score 1):

The query settings for the CQWP need to include either the list type or the content type that is used in the list. Then new lists will be included in the CQWP.

For example: The parent site collection has a CQWP that aggregates items from all Announcements lists in the sub sites. The CQWP settings look like this:

[image]

When a new Announcement list is added to a sub site, or when a new sub-site is added that includes an Announcement list, these items will show up in the CQWP.

Keep in mind that the updates may take a minute or so, since the CQWP requires a timer job to run to be updated.